# SharePoint 2010 Event Calendar with Registration Feature

Tags: 2010, calendar

I would like to use SharePoint 2010 Calendar Web Part, but I need event registration functionality.  How can I accomplish this using the out of the box Calendar Web Part.  Does anyone have any ideas on either developing code to do this or using a 3rd party solution (either a 3rd party WebPart or redirecting to a 3rd party site to handle the registration).  Basically looking for ideas.  Thanks for any provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some basic functionality from the base Calendar type and a custom form for adding items to the list.

However, you may want to look at these as well.

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=78532&av=106244

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com (search for Calendar, quite a few articles)

http://die.sharepoint-spezialisten.com/products/eventmanagement.en.php

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-calendar-plus-web-part.aspx